# tell what form a button pressed is coming from

Tags: javascript, html

I have a single page application that uses multiple forms to display data.  Most of the forms have the same input fields. I used JavaScript to create the form input fields - done once for all forms.

I can tell what form and field has been changed by looking at the form element `form1.elements["varietyName"].options[form1.elements["varietyName"].selectedIndex].text` or if it has been changed on form2.

I know how to create a button via JavaScript and populate it on multiple forms, but how can I tell what form that button was pressed on?

I can't give my button an `onclick` event, as it will be on form1 and form2. I also don't want the form to be submitted to the server when the button is clicked, so I can't use that.

Comment: You should review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try again.

Comment: `this.closest('form')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find the closest form to the current element. So, for example:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')).forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.closest('form').id)
  })
})
```

```html
<form id="a">
  <input type="button" value="click me">
</form>
<form id="b">
  <input type="button" value="click me">
</form>
```

Comment: If you ignore IE

Answer (score -1):

if your purpose is only looking for the form encapsulating a button, then its easy. Considering you have the buttonElement, you can find its parentNode and check its TagName recursively until finding the formElement.

But actually i think you got it the wrong way, you should better track the for submit event then the button click event.

Peace.